# Sprachlicher Fehler Unserer Lieben Frau in Lourdes?

Tags: single-word-request, terminology

Im Jahre 1854 verkündete Papst Pius IX. in seiner Bulle *Ineffabilis Deus* das Dogma von der unbefleckten Empfängnis Mariens. Dieses Dogma besagt, dass die Jungfrau Maria von ihrer Zeugung an frei von dem Makel der Erbsünde war. Es ist nicht mit der Jungfrauengeburt zu verwechseln! Vier Jahre später erschien die Jungfrau Maria einem 14-jährigen Mädchen, Bernadette Soubirous, in der Pyrenäenstadt Lourdes und verkündete:

> „Ich bin die unbefleckte Empfängnis!“

Diese Formulierung kommt mir auf den ersten Blick falsch vor. Eine Person kann keine Empfängnis sein. „Ich wurde unbefleckt empfangen.“, zum Beispiel, oder auch „Meine Empfängnis ist unbefleckt.“ ergäben jedenfalls mehr Sinn.

Das Originalzitat Mariens ist in gaskognischem Okzitanisch, aber auch in anderen Übersetzungen findet sich dieses sprachliche Sonderheit wieder. Der [englische Wikipedia-Artikel zu Bernadette Soubirous](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernadette_Soubirous), zum Beispiel, beschreibt den relevanten Teil der Erscheinung so (Hervorhebung von mir):

> According to Bernadette's account, during that same visitation, she
>   again asked the woman for her name but the lady just smiled back. She
>   repeated the question three more times and finally heard the lady say,
>   in Gascon Occitan, **“I am the Immaculate Conception”** (Qué soï era
>   immaculado councepcioũ, a phonetic transcription of Que soi era
>   immaculada concepcion).

Der Kirchenhistoriker und Theologe [Diarmaid MacCulloch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diarmaid_MacCulloch) scheint die Formulierung für sprachlich fehlerhaft zu halten, denn er bescheinigt Maria in *A History of Christianity: The First Three Thousand Years* „a fine disregard for logical categories“ – das Wort „fine“ ist hier wohl sarkastisch gemeint.

Mein Frage ist folgende:

1. *Angenommen, die Formulierung ist so beabsichtigt.* Handelt es sich in diesem Fall um eine rhetorische Stilfigur und wenn ja welche?
2. *Angenommen, es war ein Fehler von Maria oder Bernadette.* Wie würde man diesen Fehler im Deutschen bezeichnen oder zum Ausdruck bringen, ähnlich wie es MacCulloch im obigen Zitat auf Englisch tut („disregard for logical categories”)?

Comment: Also ich finde die Frage komisch. *Ich bin die unbefleckte Empfängnis* interpretiere ich als stilistische Variante von *Ich bin die, die unbefleckt empfangen wurde*. Quasi Maria also als die personifizierte unbefleckte Empfängnis. Die Frage ist also: liegt hier wirklich ein sprachlicher Fehler oder eher ein Verständnisproblem vor?

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar Nein nein, er scheint Recht zu haben; das, was wir meinen, ist die Jungfrauengeburt.

Comment: @Carlster Ah, ok. Das mag wohl sein. Ich ändere meinen Kommentar. Dennoch gilt meine Frage nach der korrekten Interpretation.

Comment: Ganz nebenbei, weil es in einem mittlerweile gelöschten Kommentar erwähnt wurde: Nach katholischer Lehre hat Maria nicht nur unbeflecket empfangen, sondern [wurde auch unbefleckt empfangen](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mariä_Empfängnis).

Comment: @Wrzlprmft So wie ich das verstehe, gibt es hier zwei verschiedene Bedeutungen von "unbefleckt": Das eine heißt *ohne Sex* (Empfängnis Jesu) und das andere heißt, frei von der durch Adam und Eva hergestellten Erbsünde. Letzteres ist die unbefleckte Empfängnis Mariä. Das musste päpstlicherseits anscheinend so definiert werden, da es sonst ja ein Skandal wäre, wenn Jesus von einer sündigen Mutter empfangen worden wäre. Aber ich bin auch evangelisch und muss mich daher zum Glück mit solcher Wortklauberei nicht befassen :-D

Comment: In dieser Bulle wird laut Wiki die E. so definiert: "Unter Empfängnis ist die passive Empfängnis zu verstehen, also der Augenblick, in dem die Seele von Gott erschaffen und in die Lebensmaterie, die die Eltern bereitet (gezeugt) haben, eingegossen wird."

Comment: Es handelt sich um die Aussage der damals **14-jährigen** Bernadette Soubirous: "Que soy era Immaculada Councepciou". Das Wort "era" ist offiziell der bestimmte weibliche Artikel. Bis auf die Betonung deckt sich dieser mit dem Imperfekt (für die 3. Person, Singular) von "sein". Jemand, der vielleicht die okzitanische Grammatik kennt, könnte uns sagen, ob das Spielraum für einen möglichen Passiv gibt.

Comment: Ich habe noch ein paar Anmerkungen hinzugefügt. Es geht mir nur darum, wie man diesen sprachlichen Fehler im Deutschen zum Ausdruck bringen würde, ähnlich wie es MacCulloch im Englischen tut.

Comment: [Metonymie](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synekdoche) und [Synekdoche](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metonymie) könnten weiterhelfen …

Comment: @Carlster: Deswegen ist es ja auch ein Kommentar und keine Antwort. Es könnte weiterhelfen, das Gesuchte zu finden, mehr nicht.

Comment: @mistercake Vielleicht ist es ja einfach gar kein sprachlicher Fehler? Vergleiche beispielsweise die sieben *Ich bin* Worte laut Johannes-Evangelium (http://www.christliche-autoren.de/ichbin.html). Hier personifiziert Jesus ja auch sowohl Gegenständliches als auch Abstraktes. Warum sollte Maria nicht auch *Ich bin die Unbefleckte Empfängnis* gesagt haben, anstatt, *Ich bin Maria*? Also ganz metaphorisch?

Comment: For further discussions please use [chat]. All comments will be deleted after 1) an issue was resolved, 2) details were incorporated into the question or an answer 3) the comment topic becomes off topic to the question.

Comment: Ich bezweifle ja sehr, dass eine legendäre Figur diesem Mädchen erschienen ist. Ich würde von einer angeblichen Erscheinung sprechen - die sprachliche Einordnung tangiert das freilich nicht.

Answer (score 4):

Ich bin + beliebige Tugend oä ist doch eine gängige Sprachfigur:

> Ich bin das Licht, die Gnade, die Güte, die Liebe usw.

Warum also nicht auch unbefleckte Empfängnis? Ganz allgemein sollte man die theologische Goldwaage mE den Theologen überlassen ...

Comment: Naja, der Begriff sollte zumindest in der Meinung der entsprechenden Religion irgendwie positiv besetzt sein. _Geburt_ und _Namensgebung_ sind aber wohl bloß neutral.

Comment: Wäre das für die Religion so neutral würden sie nicht ein derartiges Bohei darum machen.

Comment: Die Formulierung erinnert an das Jesus-Wort (Johannes 14,6): Ich bin der Weg und die Wahrheit und das Leben. Insoweit könnte man auch "Ich bin die unbefleckte Empfängnis" als eine Art biblische Stilfigur betrachten.

Answer (score 1):

**Angenommen, das war der tatsächliche Wortlaut:**

> 1. Mit "Immaculada Councepciou" ist das unbefleckt Empfangene - also sie selbst - gemeint.
>
>    1.1. Maria stellt sich mit der Beseelung durch Gott gleich. (?)
>
>    1.2. Die Übersetzungen stimmen nicht.
> 2. Es liegt offensichtlich kein grammatikalischer Fehler vor. Es handelt sich um eine falsche Aussage, denn eine Person - lebendig oder tot - kann keine Empfängnis sein.

Mir ist keine rhetorische Stilfigur bekannt, die das "denn" in (2) zulassen würde. Geht man von (1) aus, so wäre es wohl eine Trope, im Genaueren eine Antonomasie.

**Infragestellung des Wortlautes:**

Das Mädchen war 14 Jahre alt und lebte im 19. Jahrhundert.

> Dass Bernadette mit ihrer mangelnden Bildung und obwohl sie noch nicht bei der Erstkommunion gewesen war, von diesem Dogma gehört haben konnte, ist wenig wahrscheinlich. Bernadette war diese Bezeichnung so unbekannt, dass sie beim Zurücklaufen die Worte immer wiederholte.
>
> (Wikipedia)

So genau die Information von Wikipedia auch sein mag, allein ihr Alter in Verbindung mit der Zeit, in der sie lebte, lässt zumindest mich vermuten, dass bei der Überlieferung etwas schiefgegangen ist.

**Des Weiteren könnte bei unrichtigem Wortlaut ein**

- semantisches (onomasiologisches oder semasiologisches),

  <sup>zB das Mädchen war sich nicht über die Bedeutung der Worte im Klaren</sup>
- lexikalisches,

  <sup>das Mädchen hat aufgrund ihres geringen Wortschatzes das falsche erwischt</sup>
- kontextuelles

  <sup>es ist nicht der ganze Wortlaut</sup>
- oder auch morphologisches **Problem vorliegen.**

  <sup>andere Flexionen würden die Aussage sinnvoll werden lassen</sup>

---

**Für eine weniger sprachwissenschaftliche "Bewertung" der Aussage von Maria:**

- eine leichte Missachtung von logischen Grundsätzen
- feines Gefühl für Sinn
- unbefleckt bedeutungsschwanger uä.

Der Autor hat wohl kaum Kants oder Aristoteles' Kategorien gemeint.

Answer (score 0):

Der sprachliche Fehler könnte auch ein Hinweis darauf sein, daß die angebliche Erscheinung in Wahrheit gar nicht stattgefunden hat, weil dann der Sprachfehler ausschließlich dem Mädchen zuzuordnen ist, das vom Hörensagen einfach etwas Unverstandenes nachplapperte.